# Use constants in objective-c. Duplicate symbol issues

Tags: objective-c

I have two classes with a constants.

For example there is a class called **class_a.m** contain a constant `kWidth = 150`,

also I have a class called **class_b.m** caontain a constant `kWidth = 200`

After run my project I get an error with duplicate symbol, but these files are not nested (i mean class_a into class_b or class_b into class_a). Also i use this constantin implementation only.

Source:

```
const int kWidht = 150;
```

Error description:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _kWidht...
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please post your code. How are the variables declared? `static`?

Comment: thanks for response! i update my question. pls see it, thanks!

Comment: yes I need to use static, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the constant is only used within that single implementation file, then you should prefix its declaration with `static`. That is, turn this:

```
const int kWidth = 150;
```

into this:

```
static const int kWidth = 150;
```

The `static` keyword tells the compiler that this symbol is only used within the current file.<sub>1</sub> Without it, the compiler assumes you're declaring a *global* variable, one that could be accessed from anywhere in the final application. Declaring two global variables with the same name isn't a good idea as you'd have no way to distinguish between them, so the compiler rightly complains. Luckily, it's easy to fix this by simply being more explicit about  your intentions via the `static` keyword.

---

1: More accurately "translation unit", but "file" is good enough for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to workaround that situation, is to 'collect' all constants in a class. That way you have a better overview of all constants names. The downside is, that these can be assumed to be global variables, which is not always appreciated.